# First row of all groups in Flask SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to group the database by `gauge_id` and then get the row having maximum `time_col`. This is my current code:

```
rain_gauge_datas = db.session.query(DataEntry.gauge_id, func.max(DataEntry.time_col)).group_by(DataEntry.gauge_id).all()
```

But I am only able to get both `gauge_id` and `time_col`. When I add another column (reading), like this:

```
rain_gauge_datas = db.session.query(DataEntry.gauge_id, DataEntry.reading, func.max(DataEntry.time_col)).group_by(DataEntry.gauge_id).all()
```

it gives this error.

```
column "data_entry.reading" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

How do I return the top row of each groups? Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want the `reading` that matches `max(time_col)`?  Can there be different `reading`s for the same value of `time_col`?

Comment: I want the entire row (not just the ```reading``` column) which contains the maximum ```time_col```. Yes, there can be different ```readings``` for the same ```time_col```

Comment: So if we have two rows with the same `gauge_id` and `time_col` is the maximum, but different readings, how should we determine which row's data is selected?

Comment: There can be same ```readings``` for the same ```time_col```, but then the ```gauge_id``` will be different. So, for a given ```gauge_id```, the column ```time_col``` is unique. So, for every ```gauge_id```, I just want it to return that unique row containing maximum ```time_col```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this would be with a [common table expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) (CTE).  The CTE creates a virtual table of the group by resultset which we can then join against.

The SQL would be

```sql
with cte as (
    select gauge_id, max(time_col) as max_time
    from data_entries
    group by gauge_id
)

select d.* from data_entries d
join cte 
on d.gauge_id = cte.gauge_id 
and d.time_col = cte.max_time;
```

The SQLAlchemy equivalent would be

```py
cte = (session.query(DataEntry.gauge_id, sa.func.max(DataEntry.time_col).label('max_time'))
              .group_by(DataEntry.gauge_id)
              .cte(name='cte'))
query = session.query(DataEntry).join(cte, sa.and_(
    DataEntry.gauge_id == cte.c.gauge_id,
    DataEntry.time_col == cte.c.max_time
))
```

(the above example uses "pure" SQLAlchemy rather than Flask-SQLAlchemy - it should be enough to replace `sa.` with `db.` and `session` with `db.session` to get it working in Flask_SQLAlchemy)

It's worth noting that CTEs were not handled efficiently in Postgresql until v12, so if you are on an earlier version it may be better to inline the CTE as a subquery.